# How to remove focus on inputs after submisssion of form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm making a signup form component in React using React hooks and styled components approach. I was able to make the component but after submission, in mozilla (Developer Edition), an outline is set on all input fields. This is not so in chrome though...

Below is the component styling:

```
const Input = styled.input`
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  &::placeholder {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  &:focus,
  &:active {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a3a3a3;
}
`;
```

How do I resolve this issue? Here's what it looks like in the said browser:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try a conditional css className which you remove the focus className from the input after form submission.

Styled Component CSS: **&.hasFocus:focus**

Input prop: **< Input className={!isSubmitted ? ‘hasFocus’ : {}} / >**

Initial state:  **const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = React.useState(false);**

**onSubmit() { ...other code... setIsSubmitted(true) }**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Larissa for the response...I don't know if you could infer from the code snippet that I am using a styled-component approach. This implies I cannot have ```this.setState```. However, I'll try to understand your suggestion and see if it's adaptable.

Comment: I use styled components too. In your styled component css just add a className in front of the &:focus, so it's &.hasFocus:focus, then on your input just add className={isSubmitted ? 'hasFocus' : {}}. If you are using hooks you can put isSubmitted to the component state that way also. I'm pretty sure the approach is adaptable! Good luck!

Comment: "The useState hook allows you to declare only one state variable (of any type) at a time"

Comment: Thanks @Larisa for the response.

Answer (score -2):

Try removing border shadow:

```
&:focus,
&:active {
  ...
  border-shadow: none;
}
```